# ClassNotFoundException when transfer data between service and activity

Tags: android, ipc, bundle

I am writing an application which is composed of an underlying service and a GUI controller. The service collects data and sends to the controller, I used Messenger and put an array of parcelable objects into the bundle of the message. But when it is received at the controller side, error occurs:

android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException in unmarshalling MyData ...

I am sure that MyData implements correctly Parcelable interface. It seems I have to do something with ClassLoader? or what else? Please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: IF you don't supply some example code of what you're doing it's pretty much impossible to help.

Answer (score 1):

i got the same problem yesterday, and it was solved this way:
  set a class loader using "bundle.setClassLoader(getClassLoader());" right before "getParcelableArray" is called on that bundle.

i don't know how or why it works, but it works just fine in my code.

Comment: For me this did the trick: `bundle.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
`

Answer (score -1):

Here is part of my code:

```
    //send data from the service to the bound client

    MyData[] items; ...

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArray("items", items);
    //send in a message
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, DATA_AVAIL);
    msg.replyTo = mIncomingMessenger;
    ...
    msg.setData(bundle);

=========
//receive data 
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.what == DATA_AVAIL){
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();          
        MyData[] items = (MyData[])bundle.getParcelableArray("items");
//error happens here, classnotfound

        }
...
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to edit your question and include this there! This is not an answer